# Keychain/Foundation memory leak

Tags: ios, memory-management, keychain, foundation

I know, there is a lot of question on this topic, but i have some troubles with saving NSString into Keychain (with ARC).

Here is the code i've used:

```
+ (NSString *)getStringForKey:(NSString *)aKey
{
    NSMutableDictionary *searchDictionary = [self DictionaryForKey:aKey];
    NSString *stringValue;

    [searchDictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne forKey:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit];
    [searchDictionary setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];

    CFTypeRef result = NULL;
    OSStatus statusCode = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary, &result);
    if (statusCode == errSecSuccess)
    {
        NSData *resultData = CFBridgingRelease(result);
        stringValue =[[NSString alloc] initWithData:resultData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }

    return stringValue;

}

+ (void)setString:(NSString *)string forKey:(NSString *)aKey
{    
    if (string != nil) {
        NSData *encodedData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSMutableDictionary *keyDictionary = [self DictionaryForKey:aKey];
        [keyDictionary setObject:encodedData forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
        SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keyDictionary, nil);
    }
}
```

I've founded that sometimes `getStringForKey:` returns nil (maybe 1 time of 100). Profile shows me memory leaks every time i call this method.

[image]

I also tried to use  `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:]` but the same problem occurs - there is leak on `NSKeyedUnarchiver` instead.

I think i've missed something essential here. I followed [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.pdf) but can not solve my problem. Please, help me:)